# Australia Visitor (subclass 600) Visa - maximum 3 months study condition imposed for tourists

Tags: visas, australia

I have recently applied for a tourist visa for Australia for my trip from India to Australia for 2 weeks in January 2018. I have received the visa grant letter online. It is a visitor visa subclass 600. In that, the visa conditions are written as:

8101 - NO WORK

8201 - MAXIMUM 3 MONTHS STUDY

The maximum 3 months study condition looks awkward to me since I applied for a tourist visa for touring around in Australia and not for study. So, is it okay or not? Can someone help?

Comment: 8201 is a standard condition that is imposed on *all* subclass 600 visas.  As @Hanky Panky noted below, if you don't intend to do any study you can just note it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just fine. In case you want to take a short study course you can do so there as long is it is less than 3 months.

If you have no intention of any short term study there you can just ignore that note and enjoy the rest of permitted tourist activities.

Tourist visas are not extremely restrictive on just touring around the country they permit quite a broad range of short term activities